# How do I run a PowerShell script on an Azure App Service running Linux?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

Using SSH to remote into the App Service I'm greeted with this message:

[image]

```
root@05831a60f815:/home# pwsh
-bash: pwsh: command not found
```

It would appear that Microsoft's new PowerShell Core is not installed on Azure's Linux containers.

Where do I define that I want PowerShell to be installed on my Linux deployment?

We have defined `ubuntu-latest` as our `vmImage` in our Azure DevOps CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually can be done from `App Service Extension` under **Development Tools** line. But in this case it doesn't have any option for PowerShell, so I believe you would need to install it manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7

Comment: If I installed something manually, would it be persisted even after deploying a new version of my app?

Comment: @RubbelDieKatz nice question, don't have an answer for that. You should check, just try to restart your App, if pwsh is still present, you should be good to go with the upgrade. The main idea here is it to understand is it containerized.

Comment: The app service is running Debian 9, which apparently does not have `libicu55` and `libssl1.0.0` pre-installed. These packages are a hard requirement for PowerShell Core. I'll take a look around.

Comment: @RubbelDieKatz did you tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7#installation-via-package-repository---debian-9

Comment: Yup. Tried that. But apparently the docs aren't up to date.